# How to clean up Polymer component memory leak?

Tags: javascript, angularjs, memory-leaks, polymer-1.0

I have a angular app, which has 2 views: view foo and view bar. view foo has several polymer components(mostly custom and some paper-dialog)

Using chrome dev tool recording allocation timeline on view switching, all the polymer components on view foo would attribute to ~750k of memory leak: Once I enter to view foo, it will show a ~1Mb jump of memory usage which will never get GC, and if i commented out all the view foo polymer code, I would see 75% reduction, ~250k, which still wont get GC)

So far I have tried de-register all event listener in "detached" sections (no idea what to do for paper-dialog) But it does not seem to change the memory leak situation.

When entering the page, I can see "attached" being called, also on leaving the view, "detached" is called.

Running Angular 1.4, Polymer 0.9

Thanks!

Comment: attached and detached mentioned above are polymer attributes, just to clear it up.

Comment: Can you try with more recent release? It is quite possible that 0.9 has some memory leaks that were fixed years ago - the current releases are 1.9.x and 2.0rc.

Comment: @RichardHsu, Were you able to find any solution for the same. We are running Polymer 1.9.1 are seeing the same issue.